# "The process of formation of" - how to replace it?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to replace the sentence "The process of formation of parties began" (political parties) with the sentence "The process of parties formation began"? Does that sound correct? Or is there any other way how to express that idea so it could soung natural, since when I read this sentence I can't stop thinkink that it looks like an ugly translation.

Comment: It would be "party formation" rather than parties formation, but I don't think you need "process of", since formation is a process.  To me, it means the same without it.  So you could use just "party formation began".  Actually,  that could also describe one party rather than parties in general, so "formation of parties began" might be better because it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways:

1. **The process of forming parties began** - You just remove the second "**of**"
2. **The formation of parties began**
3. **Party formation began**